React native AsyncStorage doesn't work in the apk made with expo
Im new working with expo, I developed an application that works as expected in expo go, however when I create the apk with eas build the application does not work correctly, when I open the app it redirects me to the login, until then everything is fine, when I log in I should obtain a token which I store in AsyncStorage and after being stored it redirects me to Home, however the application does not redirect me, I checked that the api gave me the token and if it gives it to me, because of this I think that the asyncStorage does not perform its function. task correctly and does not allow me to redirect to home. this is my login code
import * as AuthSession from "expo-auth-session";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { ThemedView } from "@/components/ThemedView";
import { ThemedText } from "@/components/ThemedText";
import { styles } from "@/Styles/styles";
import { router, useSegments } from "expo-router";
import { useStateValue } from "@/Context/store";
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

import { checkToken, getAccessToken } from "@/Api/SpotifyAuth";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
export default function login() {
  const [{ sesionUsuario }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [TOKEN, setToken] = useState<string | null>('')

  const [CODE, setCode] = useState('');
  const URI = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
    native: "myapp://",
    path: "/login",
  });
  const endpoints = {
    authorizationEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize",
    tokenEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
  };
  console.log(Linking.createURL('login'))
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_CLIENTE_ID || "",
      scopes: ["user-read-email", "user-read-private", "user-top-read"],
      responseType: "code",
      redirectUri:  Linking.createURL('login') ,
      usePKCE: false,
    },
    endpoints
  );
    const storeData = async (key: string, data: string) => {
      try {


        await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw new Error('${error}');
      }

  };

  const handleResponse = async (code: string) => {
    const { data } : any = await getAccessToken(code, dispatch);
    const { refresh_token, access_token, expira } = data;
     checkToken(expira);
  if (access_token) {
      await storeData("token", access_token)
      await storeData("refresh_token", refresh_token)
      router.replace("/(tabs)");
  }
   
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value : string | null)=>{
      setToken(value);
    }).catch((e:any)=>{
      throw new Error('${e}')
    })
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { code } = response.params;
      setCode(code)
      handleResponse(code);

    }
  }, [response]);

return (
    <ThemedView style={styles.stepContainer}>
      <ThemedText type="subtitle">Conecta tu cuenta de Spotify</ThemedText>
      <Button title="Conectar" onPress={() => promptAsync()} />
      <Text>Hola</Text>
       <ThemedText>Token:{TOKEN}</ThemedText>
      <ThemedText>{Linking.createURL('login')}</ThemedText>
    </ThemedView>
  );
}

I read on github that I could add inlineRequires: false, in metro.config.js add this linear to the file, install the apk and it still doesn't work correctly

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = {
  ...defaultConfig,
  transformer: {
    ...defaultConfig.transformer,
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};```



Are you sure this is working on an emulator? This code has a lot of weird things. Please explain a little bit more about the error

yeah this work in emulator and expo go, in a few words I make a request to the Spotify api for an authentication token and I save this token in the Asynstorage, But the asynstorage lines are not executed, the promise is not fulfilled, I added some lines of code so that in the Apk it shows me things like the token And that's how I found out that the AsynStorage lines are not running

For the redirectURI, you should specify the scheme (the one you have in app.json) and the path and it's better to check if you in the dev environement or not.
It looks something like this :
    const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri(
        __DEV__ ? undefined : { scheme: "your.schema: "auth" },
    );

This way you can just pass redirectUri directly to useAuthRequest.
Also it's better to use SecureStore for your accessToken and refreshToken.
I hope this helps!
